# PCB usb powered - led and screen wiring + review schematic

Tags: stm32, wiring, ws2812b, schematic

I'm currently designing a PCB featuring an STM32F103CBT6 MCU. The PCB will host five different groups of WS2812B LEDs, multiplexed 22 pushbuttons, 4 rotary encoders, and additionally, a VoCore 5" screen will be connected to the PCB. The challenge is that I can't use an additional power supply other than a powered USB hub, as the PCB will be integrated into a steering wheel and only has a USB connection. As a result, I am considering reducing the number of LEDs on the pushbutton backlight group if needed.

Here's the breakdown of LED groups:

- Backlight pushbuttons: 46x WS2812B 2121
- Engine rpm: 10x WS2812B 5050
- Fuel indicators left: 3x WS2812B 5050
- Fuel indicators right: 3x WS2812B 5050
- Encoder backlights: 16x WS2812B 5050

I have several questions regarding the LED and VoCore wiring components:

**Capacitor Requirement for WS2812B LEDs:**

1. WS2812B LEDs already have a built-in capacitor. Additionally, I have a 10uF capacitor on the 5V line before the AMS1117-3.3 chip. Do I need to add more capacitors before each group of WS2812B LEDs? If so, is one before each group sufficient, or does every LED need one? So one of the following configurations should be correct:

- USB 5V -> 10uF -> WS2812B LED group
- USB 5V -> 10uF -> Another capacitor (100uF?) -> WS2812B LED group

2. Can I directly wire the data in pin from the LED to a GPIO pin on the MCU?

**Powering VoCore Screen:**

1. The PCB will connect to a VoCore screen via USB Micro. Can I directly connect 5V to the USB's 5V? Or does the screen require an extra capacitor? I assume the screen will have its own power circuit on the PCB itself.
2. Also, is it true that I need to invert RX and TX between the VoCore and STM32F103CBT6? Thus:
   a.  VoCore RX -> STM32F103CBT6 TX
   b.  VoCore TX -> STM32F103CBT6 RX

I'd appreciate any insights or advice regarding these questions. Thank you in advance for your help!

Below, I have included some screenshots from my diagram (MCU, power supply, multiplexing, and LEDs).

5v -> 3.3v:
[image: 5v -> 3.3v:]

Pushbuttons and encoders multiplexed:
[image: Pushbuttons and encoders multiplexed]

WS2812B leds, each group:
[image]

Comment: Can you ask a specific question?

Comment: Do I need to add more capacitors before each group of WS2812B LEDs? 
Can I directly wire the data in pin from the LED to a GPIO pin on the MCU?
Can I directly connect 5V to the USB's 5V? 
 is it true that I need to invert RX and TX between the VoCore and STM32F103CBT6?

Comment: Is USB-PD an option?  Right now your power requirements appear to significantly outstrip the normal limits.

Comment: "Can I directly wire the data in pin from the LED to a GPIO pin on the MCU?"  This depends on what batch of WS2812B you have.  The original design was for 5V logic level (where the *minimum* voltage interpreted as high was 3.6V, more than your GPIO can produce).